# Automysqlbackup does not use the configured password

Tags: mysql, debian, backup, debian-bullseye

I have [automysqlbackup](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.8.en.html) installed on debian. I added USERNAME and PASSWORD to `/etc/default/automysqlbackup`, but when automysqlbackup runs, I get the output:

```
/etc/cron.daily/automysqlbackup:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO
```

as if I would not have configured any credentials.

The automysqlbackup config is the default configuration with two lines added at the end:

```
USERNAME=root
PASSWORD="the root password"
```

The default config tries to get the credentials from `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` (using grep in the `/etc/default/automysqlbackup` bash snippet) which contains a warning that the file is deprecated and does not contain any admin password anymore on new installations.

I tried automysqlbackup with strace and it at least reads `/etc/default/automysqlbackup` even when not started by cron. It doesn't use the password, though.

Comment: Can you show us your config?

Comment: @vidarlo I added it to the question, but I only changed USERNAME and PASSWORD, as it tries by default to get it from `debian.cnf` which is deprecated and does not contain a password anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was to append the USERNAME and PASSWORD at the end of the file, while the file is evaluated as shellscript and contains some `mysql` commands to list database names that already require a login.

It also seems to make strong assumentions that `debian.cnf` is available and contains the needed credentials, by finding databases like this:

```
DBNAMES=`mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf --execute="SHOW DATABASES" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v ^Database$ | grep -v ^mysql$ | grep -v ^performance_schema$ | grep -v ^information_schema$ | tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `
```

which would probably need parameters to use `$USERNAME` and `$PASSWORD` instead of the deprecated defaults file.

I know that old mysql/mariadb packages configured a maintenance user in `debian.cnf` but a fresh install does not contain such a account and so the script already fails when trying to list the databases.

The configuration file already contains a commented out alternative that seems to work:

```
DBNAMES=`find /var/lib/mysql -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -d'/' -f5 | grep -v ^mysql\$ | tr \\\r\\\n ,\ `
```

I must say, that both lines look a bit fragile to me. I am not sure if this won't break sometime and if the whole automysqlbackup script or at least its configuration may not be the most robust solution.